# What version of Mockito is springockito-annotations compatible with?

Tags: mockito, springockito

I'm using (or rather: tried using) `Mockito 1.10.19` and `springockito-annotatinos 1.0.9`, but they don't agree with each other.

(I get a `ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.internal.MockitoInvocationHandler` and have raised a [bug](https://github.com/springockito/springockito/issues/7) with `springockito`.)

**Does anyone have a list of what version of Mockito `springockito-annotatinos` works with?** (Or is someone successfully using `springockito-annotatinos` and can share what version of Mockito they use?)

I'm expecting the compatibilities will be as confusing as [those between PowerMock and Mockito for PowerMockito](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockitousage#supported-versions)...

Comment: I have no idea what mockito is but I gotta shout out for whoever is coming up with the names for these things! :D

Comment: **Update**: Apparently, the last version of Mockito that had the missing class was Mockito 1.9.0; cf. bug report linked above. That doesn't tell me which versions are compatible, but it does tell me which ones aren't. Does anyone know if [springockito](http://www.springockito.org/) is still being maintained, or is it just being hosted on github?